# python global variable inside a module

Tags: python, module, global-variables

a.py contains:

```
ip=raw_input()
import b
show()
```

b.py contains:

```
def show:
    global ip
    print ip
```

it's showing an error saying that ip is not defined.
how can i use a variable from the main script inside a module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A global declaration *prevents a local variable being created by an assignment*. It doesn't magically search for a variable.

Unless you import a variable from one module to another, it is not available in other modules.

For `b` to be able to access members of `a`, you would need to import `a`. You can't, because `a` imports `b`.

The solution here is probably just not to use global variables at all.

Answer (score 0):

The way your code is structured, it implies to me that you're treating `import` as if it were effectively copying-and-pasting the contents of `b.py` into `a.py`. However, that's not how Python works -- variables and functions inside one module will not be accessible in another unless explicitly passed in via a function, or by using the `module.member` notation.

Try doing this instead:

a.py:

```
import b

ip = raw_input()
b.show(ip)
```

b.py:

```
def show(ip):
    print ip
```

If you need to do some processing within the `b` module, pass in the relevant functions, make any changes, and return them. Then, reassign them within the calling module.

Edit: if you must use globals, change b.py to look like this:

```
ip = None

def show(temp):
    global ip
    ip = temp

    # code here

    print ip
```

...but it would be more ideal to restructure so that you don't end up using globals.

Comment: i know that i can pass via parameter. but inside `b.py` i've three functions which is called one after another from `show()` (sometimes recursively). so i need anyhow the `ip` as a global one. else it'll create many local variables for each call which will be of no use. is there any other method?

Comment: @RatDon -- I edited my answer. Since I don't know how your code is structured, I don't know if this will work or not, but try giving it a shot?

Comment: @ whoever just downvoted -- what I can I do to improve the answer?

Comment: This is not an answer to the original question, but a workaround for the toy example.